# Applescript : Click at position not working

Tags: applescript, google-chrome, ui, click

[image: Screenshot]

I'm trying to click on a Chrome extension ( Google Highlight  : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/multi-highlight/pfgfgjlejbbpfmcfjhdmikihihddeeji) then click on the text box and past my variables.

here is my code

```
set NoteforGoogleCHrome to "My text should be there"

tell application "Google Chrome"
    activate
end tell
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Google Chrome"

        delay 2
        click button 8 of toolbar 2 of window "myTab" of application process "Google Chrome" of application "System Events"
        delay 0.2
        keystroke tab
        delay 0.2
        keystroke NoteforGoogleCHrome
        delay 0.2
        keystroke space
    end tell
end tell
```

I tried this but this is most of the time failing.

When I'm trying to click on the text field (CLICK 2) I always have an error :

> click process "Google Chrome" at {4000, 114}      --> missing value

However if I do the same for CLICK 1 I have no error.

Can you give me some advice ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works for me in macOS High Sierra 10.13.5 and Google Chrome 67.0.3396.99.

**Example AppleScript *code*:**

```
set NoteforGoogleCHrome to "click me"

tell application "Google Chrome" to activate
delay 0.5
tell application "System Events"
    click (every UI element of toolbar 2 of front window of application process "Chrome" whose help is "Multi-highlight")
    delay 1
    key code 48 -- # Tab Key
    delay 0.2
    keystroke NoteforGoogleCHrome & space
end tell
```

As you can see in the image below, it highlighted all occurrences of `click` and `me`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I’ll try it tomorrow morning but that make sense.